# Azure EventHubs EventProcessorHost tries to acess Azure storage queue

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub, azure-webjobssdk

After enabling app insights on a webjobs which listens for events on an EventHub using the EventProcessor class, we see that it tries continuously to access a set of non-existing queues in the configured blob storage account. We have not configured any queues on this account.

There's no reference to a queue anywhere in my code, and it is my understanding that the EventProcessorHost uses blob storage and not queues in order to maintain state. So: Why is it trying to access queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queue access that you're seeing comes from the `JobHost` itself, not from any specific trigger type like EventHubs. The WebJobs SDK uses some storage resources itself behind the scenes for its own operation, e.g. control queues to track its own work, blobs for storage of log information shown in the Dashboard, etc.

In the specific case you mention above, those control queues that are being accessed are part of our Dashboard Invoke/Replay/Abort support. We have an open issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/770) in our repo tracking potential improvements we can make in this area. Please feel free to chime in on that issue.

Comment: thanks @mathewc. So, nothing for me to do except wait for an updated version of the sdk. Marking as answer.